# Can we estimate Big Omega just like we do with Big O?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computer-science

I keep reading how easy it is to estimate Big O: drop least dominant terms and constants. My question is, can we do the same for Big Omega?

I know input dependency has nothing to do with asymptotic analysis: we can have an upper (Big O) and lower (Big Omega) on best, average and worst case analysis. But I am confused on how I can quickly estimate Big Omega of my algorithm, in the worst case for example.

If you could provide examples to clarify my confusion I would truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just two examples should enlighten you.

`n² + n` is `O(n²)` (it is also `O(n³)`).

`n² + n` is `Ω(n²)` (it is also `Ω(n)`).

You consider the dominant term.

`n + (n cos n)²` is `O(n²)` and `Ω(n)`.

Upper and lower bound.

Comment: So when you have a fixed cost function, what you always estimate by dropping constants and least dominant terms is the Theta since both O and Omega are the same?

Comment: The second example clarifies my question

Comment: Is `n + (n cos n)²` also `Ω(n²)`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 no.

Comment: @GeorgeLuisKoubbe But the function also grows no slower than `n²`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Correct, but that would be the upper bound (cos = 1). For the lower bound (cos = 0), it cannot get faster than n.

Comment: @GeorgeLuisKoubbe I think you're describing worst-case and best-case inputs. So we can say it has a worst-case lower bound of `Ω(n²)` and a best case lower bound of `Ω(n)`.

Comment: @0x499602D2: don't make the confusion between lower/upper bound and best/worst case. What we are discussing here does not involve the complexity of an algorithm, it applies to just "functions". Best and worst case would be two different functions.